# mask output of the input field

Tags: javascript

is there any way to mask the output of the input field once passed to the next page

> Enter Card : 123456789011

after the data has been passed onto the next page
when displayed it should look like this

> ```
> Card info: ********9011
> ```

the first 8 digits was converted to asterisk and
the last 4 digits of the card is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already ensured that the card number is a valid length:

```
card = "123456789011";
output = "********" + card.substring(card.length-4);
```

is all you'll need. Output will now be as you wanted, and although Starx's answer is dynamic: it's also overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
var card = "123456789011";
var str = "";

//Create the "*" for exactly 4 digits short
for(var i=1; i <= card.length-4; i++) {
   str += "*";
}
//Join the asterisk and last 4 characters
ecard = str + card.substr(card.length-4);

console.log(ecard);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdRTR/)

Comment: @telexper, Check your console... you should see the output.